# Shell - Syntax error in expression (error token is "16")

Tags: bash, shell, syntax, sum

I am doing a project for my university, and this is the first time I'm coding using Bash.

I am trying to go trough a .txt document, reading every line, and taking the information I need to make a sum.

The .txt document looks something like this:

> 83210:Henrique Gaspar:EIB2:911235444:metas@gmail.com:carro:BMW:82-RX-14:5:25:26
>   88110:Vasco Rapido:IB2:962222222:vrapid@gmail.com:mota:BMW:33-MT-99:3:5:16
>   88020:Maria Aguiar:EIB2:911555444:mguiar@gmail.com:carro:mercedes:88-TX-11:2:20:12

And for what I am doing I need to make the total sum of last number of each user, so 26+16+12.

Now, here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "Nº de condutores: "
echo $(cat condutores.txt | wc -l)
echo -n "Nº de passageiros: "
echo $(cat passageiros.txt | wc -l)
echo -n "Saldo total dos condutores: "
x=0
linhas=$(cat condutores.txt | wc -l)
i=0
while [[ $i -le $linhas ]]; do
    sum=$(cat condutores.txt | head -$i | tail -$(( $linhas + 1 - $i )) | cut -d':' -f11)
    x=$((x+sum))
    i=$((i+1))
done
echo "$x"
```

I wrote it in full here so nothing gets missed out.

What matters for the problem here is from line 7 to 15.
I don't know if it is the way I am going through each line of the condutores.txt file or any other thing. But I am getting this error:

```
Saldo total dos condutores: ./stats.sh: line 12: 26
16: syntax error in expression (error token is "16")
26
```

So for some reason it only reads the first and second line of the .txt document, but can't make the sum, can anyone help me here please? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your `$sum` contains more than one line, so it cannot be interpreted as number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $sum contains more than one line, so it cannot be interpreted as number. And your text processing loop is a nightmare, there is a more cleaner solution. Look:

```
x=0
while IFS=: read -r a b c d e f g h i j k; do
    x=$((x+k))
done < condutores.txt
echo "$x"
```